# link a custom page into menu

Tags: pages, page-template

Ok i have a file which named,

```
page-allpost.php
```

now I have a menu item called "all post" and in that menu I want to call the page-allpost.php which will display all the post. how to do that?

hope someone here could help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the file a [template header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), then create a page under Pages in admin, and assign that template to the page. You can then add that page you created to your menu.